# Reverse current on voltage regulator by PC voltage to microcontroller

Tags: microcontroller, circuit-analysis, pcb-design, voltage-regulator, switch-mode-power-supply

I've built a custom PCB with an SMPS (UK-230V) and a microcontroller (Vdd=3.3V) and I'm having a hard time flashing memory of the microcontroller because the SMPS produces unstable GND noise in my PCB.

So, I decided to flash the memory of MCU by connecting it to the USB port of my computer. However, I'm concerned about reverse current on the voltage regulator. I've tested the voltage on the input and output of the voltage regulator while I'm only using the power from the PC and I got 3.3V on both sides.

This is the shot of my circuit and [datasheet](https://www.diodes.com/assets/Datasheets/AP2112.pdf) of the voltage regulator that I used.
[image]

Please let me know if this reverse current could damage the voltage regulator over time and there is a solution to this problem. Many thanks to the amazing engineers in this forum.

Comment: Can you add the layout of the PCB?

Comment: If you have worries (and the data sheet isn't clear) then put a normally reversed diode from output to input.

Comment: There is no way to figure out how the PC can power your MCU with 3.3V. Please explain how 5V from USB ends up being 3.3V at your MCU.

Comment: I used USB to UART bridge and it converts 5V to 3.3V

Comment: What does the data sheet say about reverse protection? The data sheet you linked to is in a format that does not display in a readable format on my machine. If space is not a problem follow Andy's suggestion with a diode. Some regulators have reverse protection some do not.

Answer (score 1):

You will notice this part is CMOS and may recall that failure mode was for BJT LDO's.  The reason for that failure mode is basically the reverse voltage rating on most Vbe's and LED's is -5V and if the output had voltage higher than 5V with the input off then grounded, the output storage cap could induce failure. Thus the reverse diode pulls down the output for the situations where a power source shunts the output to 0V quickly.

None of the above conditions exist for this device and nor is there any NTE spec.

Non issue.

However there may be weird situations from the final App Note where the foldback function might be triggered if the output is externally active before the input with a current source.

### Note: (wrong question asked)

The real issue is your Flash download communication.

This can even happen on USB cables from an earth grounded PC tower to an Arduino with its own floating supply.

The problem is the RF leakage current of the HV transformer even though it is "floating" at DC.  This is a common mode noise so a differential cap will not help. But it becomes a differential noise on the unbalanced serial data and clock lines with ground to the PC.

Without knowing exact details of your system power and ground layout and interface cables during this failure mode, I have two suggestions.

1. Use a "floating" laptop for the flash port.
2. Add an RF cap(10nF) from DC 0V to earth ground of suspicious supply.

Comment: I understand that I get ripple voltage from my SMPS so therefore the differential noise on the unbalanced serial data and clock lines with the ground to the PC. That is why I'd like to use the laptop to flash the memory. However, if I do that 3.3V will go to the output of the voltage regulator and it results in 3.3V on the input of the voltage regulator. My question is if it's healthy to have 3.3V on the input of the voltage regulator?  Also, this 3.3V goes till the input of the 5V voltage regulator that I have on PCB (Whole PCB design: 230v - 12v - 5v - 3.3v)

Comment: You may short ground the input of this 3.3V LDO without issues. The 5V LDO will have no issues either but it if pulls up and logic, let me know. That might be cause for a latchup with 5V power up. I suggested the proper solution with RF to earth ground and use the proper power supply to the inputs.